# Get Uri of my Image bitmap in imageview container 1

Tags: firebase

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultcode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
      Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
       if ((extras2 != null)) {
            Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            buttonGallery.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

This is my part of code to get an image and show in image button. I want to get the URI of the image to send it to a database.

How can I get the URI of the image?